How to Measure the depth of a Hole by Dropping a Rock?
Let's say I have a rock and a stopwatch.
I am standing on the edge of a deep hole or canyon, and can see the bottom.
How would I go about measuring the depth of the hole?

Is your question about how to determine a height $y$ by knowing the time travelled by a body of mass $m$ in free fall from $y$ to $y=0$? If so, maybe look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Uniform_gravitational_field_without_air_resistance.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/18140/2451

drop the rock and start the stopwatch. Stop the watch when you see the rock smack into the bottom; call this time t. Knowing the value of gravity, plug t into the equation of motion and solve for the distance x through which the rock fell.
Alternatively, drop the rock and start the stopwatch when you see the rock hit bottom and stop it when you hear the impact; call this time t. Knowing the speed of sound in air, multiply that by t to obtain the depth of the hole.
If the rock is valuable, sell it to an unsuspecting bystander and buy a survey map that reveals the depth of the canyon, or bribe the park ranger standing nearby with the rock as a gift to get her to tell you how deep the canyon is.
If it is not, then sell the stopwatch instead and proceed as above (thanks to user mmesser314 for this handy and expedient method).
if you have a rope handy, tie it to the rock and lower it into the hole until it touches bottom, then pull it back up again and measure the length of the rope using the rock's diameter as a unit of measure.
Alternatively, lower the rock to the bottom of the hole and set it swinging like a pendulum. measure the period with the stopwatch and use the pendulum formula to solve for the pendulum length.
If you do not have a rope, you can always take the rock and carefully climb down the hole while marking off rock diameters on the wall of the hole as you descend. When you get to the bottom, sum up the count of diameters to yield the hole depth in units of rock diameters. Repeat the process on the way back up to check your work.

The way the middle part of this reads gives me feelings of Douglas Adams/Terry Pratchett +1.

The rock may not be valuable, but surely the stopwatch is.

On the subject of rock diameters, this doesn't necessarily take into account curvature of the walls like under and over hangs which will overestimate your distance...this at least gives you some upper bound though. Make sure to do suitable analysis when finding odd protrusions.

I should have clarified, I thought it would be understood. But this answer made my day, lol

Ah, the Feynman answer.

@PM2Ring, I heard it ascribed to Bohr.

You're right, but (sadly) the tale is apocryphal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question

@PM2Ring Ah well, so it goes. -NN

Drop the rock from the edge when the stopwatch is at 00:00 and as the rock hits the ground stop the time and note it.
Now use $S = 4.9 t^{2}$ put the time in this eqn and you will the depth $s$.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
